# Symfony - sonata, commit to own git repository

Tags: git, symfony1, symfony-sonata

I have the next question: My colleague cloned the symfony sonata git repository. He did the install which pulls alot of different vendor repo's.

Then he removed all the .git files, initiated a git repository and pushed everything to our remote git repository.

I cloned our repo, but nothing works. So I had to remove the .git, initiate a new repo and then do the install myself.

What we have now is each a git repository locally that is not linked to the remote repository, and the vendor bundles are not anymore tracking their repo.

Does anyone have a good workflow for setting up a sonata install on your own git repository while your vendor bundles are still tracking their repo's and symfony does as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- create a new Symfony project (using [this](http://symfony.com/download))
- tweak your .gitignore file
- then follow installation instructions for each bundle (here's an example for the [Sonata PageBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/installation.html))

Unless special circumstances, you should **ignore** the vendors directory in your repo and manage dependencies using `deps` or [composer](https://github.com/composer/composer). If you really have to somewhat "commit" your vendor dependencies, then I'd suggest using `git submodules`.

Here's a sample .gitignore file:

```
vendor/*
app/bootstrap*
*/logs/*
*/cache/*
```